# too many indices for array: array is 0-dimensional, but 1 were indexed

Tags: data-science

after applying this code
X_train=pd.DataFrame(preprocessor.fit_transform(X_train),columns=preprocessor.get_feature_names_out())
X_test=pd.DataFrame(preprocessor.transform(X_test),columns=preprocessor.get_feature_names_out())

## i am getting this error

IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 0-dimensional, but 1 were indexed

Comment: `X_train` and `X_test` have to be two-dimensional numpy arrays. Looks like you have one-dimensional numpy array. You can use `X_train.shape` to print the shape of `X_train` array for instance.